# How to reverse an array in PHP that is fetched from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to pull out a row of data from MySQL and put it in an array and then reverse it before displaying the results and then if confirmed by the user it will post the reversed results back into mysql

I am using this code :

```
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++) {
// Make a MySQL Connection
$query = "SELECT * FROM databasedemo WHERE id='$i'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
array_reverse($row,true);
echo $i."--"."A".$row['A']. " - ". "B".$row['B']. " - ". "C".$row['C']. " - ". "D".$row['D']. " - ". "E".$row['E'];
echo "<br>";
}
```

I am getting this error

```
Warning: array_reverse() [function.array-reverse]: The argument should be an array in /home/nlp4mark/public_html/Databasedemo/main.php on line 37
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if you var_dump($row) right after $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
what do you get?

Comment: does it work fine without array_reverse()? That error seems to sat that it isnt a true array.

Comment: array_reverse((array)$row,true);

Comment: if I var($row) I get the following array(12) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "1" ["A"]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "2" ["B"]=> string(1) "2" [3]=> string(1) "3" ["C"]=> string(1) "3" [4]=> string(1) "4" ["D"]=> string(1) "4" [5]=> string(1) "5" ["E"]=> string(1) "5" }

Comment: Using `array_reverse()` is completely worthless in this case when you are specifically displaying the output.

Comment: Steve when I use array_reverse((array)$row,true); the error certainly disappears and the reverse happens, but the keys are also reversed. How do I keep the keys in the same order, but reverse the results?

Comment: What are you trying to reverse? If you are using specific array keys to display results, there isn't any reason to reverse the array. Reversing an array only makes sense if you are looping over an array's  keys and values.

Comment: I am trying to learn to code something that can import a csv file into a database and then manipulate it in a variety of ways. Eg reverse it, assign rows to columns etc. I want the echo statements to reflect what has happened with the array so I can see it before updating the new values back to the database.

Comment: Every time you query inside a loop a puppy dies. Add 'WHERE id < 6'  and then loop through your results...

Answer (score 3):

You should only be executing this query once and then iterating through the results and displaying them:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM databasedemo ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM databasedemo WHERE id='$i'";
```

That query will return a one record at the time. You are sending it 6 times with the for loop, that's why you get all the records, but you send 6 times a slighty different query.

try sending one query that return all the 6 records and then reverse it. It would be something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM databasedemo WHERE 1=1";
for($i=0;i<6;$i++){
    $sql .= " AND id=$i";
}
```

Comment: This would produce a query like `SELECT * FROM databasedemo WHERE 1=1 AND id=0 AND id=1 AND id=2 AND id=3 AND id=4 AND id=5` - which will never find a result.  Either try an OR in there, or else use IN.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make any sens to me ;)

Answer (score 0):

do  like this

```
select * from  (SELECT * from messages INNER JOIN logindata ON messages.author = logindata.id ORDER BY messages.mid DESC LIMIT 0,10) as t ORDER BY t.mid asc
```